# Group of multiple dynamically generated checkbox getting whole value inside an array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, checkbox

My code

Checkbox1: Generated from json list

```
tr.append($("<td />").html('<input type="checkbox" id="reqid" name="reqid[]" value='+item+'>'));
```

Checkbox2: Generated from another json list

```
tr.append($("<td />").html('<input type="checkbox" id="selector" name="selector[]" value='+item[0]+'>'));
```

I want to get values of both checkboxes in a separate array. Please help me :)

I used the below code but the array val returns values of both the checkboxes

var val = [ ];

```
    `$`(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
    val[i] = `$`(this).val();
    alert(val[i]);
```

});

I need to get both the checkbox values in a separate textboxes called reqid[ ] and slectid[ ]

Comment: Please provide more detail. This is not a clear question

Comment: Hi, i have two dynamically generated checkboxes called reqid[] and selector[] and i want to get values of both the checkboxes in a separate array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this i guess you don't have same id applied on multiple checkboxes:

```
var data = {};
    data.chk1 = [];
    data.chk2 = [];

$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){ 
    if(this.id == "reqid"){
        data.chk1.push(this.value);
    }else if(this.id == "selector"){
        data.chk2.push(this.value);
    }
});

console.log(data.chk1 + ":::" + data.chk2);
```

As you have given `id` attribute to the checkboxes then you can have the values with the ids.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar correct but it does not seem to be like that in the question.

Comment: I have doubt in Angularjs, i think your are an expert in Angularjs @Jai

Comment: I have a doubt in cascading dropdown using angularjs which i got from a website the code is working but i am unable to get the value of third dropdown. I think you can help me :)

Comment: all right you can ask it but better you should post a **plnkr** demo.

Comment: Where should i post my code snippet here or as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:eq(0)` and `:eq(1)` to target first and second elements:

```
var Checkboxes1=$('tr :checkbox:eq(0)').map(function() {
   return this.value;
}).get();


var Checkboxes2=$('tr :checkbox:eq(1)').map(function() {
   return this.value;
}).get();
```